# Logrotate script not uploading to s3

Tags: logging, cron, amazon-s3, logrotate, s3cmd

I am trying to use logrotate to upload log files from my rails and nginx commands once a day. When I run the logrotate command manually the files successfully upload, but it never does it on its own. I have tried using lastaction and also postrotate but neither actually uploads to S3. Is there something trivial that I'm missing?

```
/home/deploy/www/mysite.com/log/*log {
su
daily
dateext
dateformat _%Y_%m_%d
rotate 3
missingok
dateext
compress
delaycompress
notifempty
copytruncate
sharedscripts
lastaction
  rvmsudo passenger-config reopen-logs;
  /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /home/deploy/www/mysite.com/log/*.gz s3://mysite_com/logs/rails/
endscript
}
```

EDIT: Below is the corrected way of doing this.
So instead of using the lastaction script, call a shell script instead.

```
lastaction
  ./rails_reload_and_upload.sh
endscript
```

which contains

```
#/bin/bash

./reload_rails_logs.sh
/usr/bin/s3cmd --config /home/username/.s3cfg sync /home/deploy/www/mysite.com/log/*.gz s3://mysite_com/logs/rails/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's most likely that either `rvmsudo` or `s3cmd` need extra environment variables to run successfully, which aren't set in the context of logrotate, but which are in your interactive shell session.  I wouldn't be surprised if `rvmsudo` isn't available in the restrictive `PATH` which cron sets.

Comment: Yup that was the issue. By emulating the cron environment using `env -i $SHELL --norc` I was able to figure out what configuration parameters I needed to use.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are running EC2 servers**,
other than running a sperate bash script, one can add an Instance Profile to EC2 server so that **aws s3 rsync** does not need access key which cannot be assigned under cron job.

So the following logrotate config runs pretty well if Instance Profile added on the running EC2 server

```
/home/ubuntu//logs/*.log {
        copytruncate
        daily
        dateext
        rotate 30
        compress
        missingok
        su root root
        lastaction
                HOSTNAME=$(/bin/hostname -f)
                DD=$(/bin/date +%d)
                MM=$(/bin/date +%m)
                YYYY=$(/bin/date +%Y)
                BUCKET="s3://xxx-logs-archive/$YYYY/$MM/$DD/batch/$HOSTNAME/"
                FILE="/home/ubuntu/logs/batch.log-$YYYY$MM$DD.gz"
                /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp "$FILE" "$BUCKET"
        endscript
}
```